# ControlGetText get from ClassNN to Number

Tags: numbers, autohotkey

[ClassNN= TDBEditArpa16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXqil.png)

I want AutoHotKey to get this value as a number and save it to an integer variable. How can I do this?

Note: I tried to do it through the following code, but the program can not identify it as a number.

```
 ControlGetText, qtp1, TDBEditArpa16, Alteração de Produtos, Informações de Custo
StringTrimRight, qtp1, qtp1, 4
qtp1 = (%qtp1% + 2)

msgbox %qtp1%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Storing the result of an [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions):**

To assign a result to a variable, use the := operator.

```
ControlGetText, qtp1, TDBEditArpa16, Alteração de Produtos, Informações de Custo
StringTrimRight, qtp1, qtp1, 4
qtp1 := (qtp1 + 2)

msgbox %qtp1%
```

Variable names in an expression are not enclosed in percent signs